# Can't connect to SQL Server Express anymore

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I think I made a mistake and I lost my connection to my SQL Server Express.

In SQL Server Management Studio under security I disabled the login option.

Now when I try to connect to the Server I get the message :

> "Cannot connect to
>   HP16969\SQLEXPRESS". Additional
>   informations : Login failed for user
>   'HP16969\Bernard (Microsoft SQL
>   Server, error : 18456)

Is there a way I can correct my earlier mistake ?

Thanks

I really have tried everything but can't connect anymore to SQLEXPRESS. Just because I change The login status to Disabled there seems to be no way for me to reconnect. That is silly!!

I followed the instructions including -m; in the parameter list without any success.
The  last option I would like to use is to reinstall Server EXPRESS .After reading many articles on the net I am scared to run into problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect using a login that has access and grant yourself again access back.

If you don't have any login that has access, then you need to restart the server in administrative mode and use a local administrator account to enable back the account 'HP16969\Bernard'. See [Troubleshooting: Connecting to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx).